# 2011 Honda CBR250r

Tags: honda, motorcycle, cbr250r

Has anyone ridden this bike at all? How does it do at 70 MPH freeway speeds?

Comment: Is there a way you can edit your question to make it apply to maintenance and repair?  I think your "driving question" may be closed as off-topic as per this meta topic:  http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-driving-questions-on-topic/4#4

Comment: Hmm, not really. That's all I wanted to know. This bike is not even officially launched yet. How would I remove this question?

Comment: should be a delete link you can click under the Honda tag. link|edit|close|delete|flag

Comment: It wouldn't let me delete it. Flagged it so moderators can clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

I did my introductory bike course on a 2011 CBR250 (which I believe is quite different from the '86-97 models, which I'm not familiar with). It's a great little bike, but I'm not sure it can do 70 MPH. ;)

The CBR250 would be ideal in the city. It's small and lightweight, handles beautifully, and I found it quite forgiving as a new rider. It definitely lacked long-haul comfort and highway power, though. Mechanically, it seemed solid but putting it in neutral was a bit of a pain at times because of the way the gear lever caught.

I landed on a Ninja 500R for my first bike (after learning on the CBR250), which was a better choice (in my opinion).

I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Hmm, I was reading these reviews online and somebody also posted a video on youtube with bike top speed. They gave me an impression that it was about 150 KMPH, which would come around 90 MPH. That is probably not true then, seems to be a lot for a 250 CC bike.

Comment: Downhill maybe. :)

Comment: 90mph sounds about right for a 250cc 'cycle.